# git log --all to ignore disconnected parts of history graph

Tags: git, git-log, git-subtree

A regular `git log` only lists the ancestors of the current commit.

With the `--all` parameter (preferably combined with `--graph`), it lists the ancestors of all refs. Usually these other refs and commits are somehow connected to the current commit. They can be ancestors, descendants, or some kind of direct or indirect "siblings". Or in other words, you could find a path through the graph from the current commit to any other commit shown with `git log --all`.

If you start playing with `git subtree`, and fetch from other subtree remotes, you will get commits that are not in any way connected to the main history. These are still listed with `git log --all`. And this can get confusing.

Questions:

- Is there a trick to exclude disconnected commits from history display?
- Is there a trick to have a better visual distinction between connected and disconnected pieces of the history graph?

---

Note: I am using the following aliases for git log:

```
lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
```